# Trouble with JQuery in Rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm simply trying to get Jquery to work with my rails application.

I'd like to place some JQuery in my new.html.erb file and I'm getting the following error in chrome's console:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Here is my new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, "New Stat") %>
<% provide(:heading, "Welcome, #{ current_user.email }!") %>

<div id="stats-page-container">
  <div id="stat-form" >
    <div id="stat-form-inner"> 

    <% render 'layouts/init_stats_form' %> 
    <% render 'layouts/stat_input_form' %>

    <script>
       $.('#stat-form-inner').addClass('test-class');
    </script>

   </div>
 </div>
  <%= render 'layouts/progress' %> 
</div>
```

The error is in the line with the JQuery code:

```
$.('#stat-form-inner').addClass('test-class');
```

Here's my application.html.erb file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>    
  <h1> <%= yield(:heading) %> </h1>  
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}")%>
  <% end %>

  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'layouts/subheader' %>
  <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>  
</body>
</html>
```

And the element with that id stat-form-inner does not have that class added to it.

my application.js file has this in it:

```
// = require jquery
// = require jquery_ujs
// = require_tree .
```

I've also added

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

directly above the ending body tag.

What else am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the '.' operator is required after $. Just remove it and check

Comment: That gives me this:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined new:63
(anonymous function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure JQuery is loaded properly. To do this, Remove/comment the $('#stat-form-inner').addClass('test-class') and open the app in FF/chrome and type $ or jQuery in the Firebug console. If it prints function(), then jQuery is loaded properly. If it throws an error **Reference Error, jQuery is not defined**, then the JQuery framework is not loaded.
2. If JQuery is loaded properly, then try the following suggestions

   Place this statement **<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>** inside the head tag or at the top of your view/layout file.

   Try the below code segment to add the class to the element, preferably at the end of the page (its okay to put this even after the closing HTML tag)

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#stat-form-inner').addClass('test-class');
      });
   </script>
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yea this did it.

I feel dumb now lol! 

I placed the script within the element instead of at the end of the template... This is what happens when you code with too little caffein or sleep :D Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Put your scripts in the folder `app/assets/javascript`, making sure to use `$("...")`, not `$.()`.

Welcome to Rails!

Comment: I'm adding this script directly to the new.html.erb page so that later I can use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the javascript_include_tag above the ending body tag.  So this means that your script is being executed before the page loads jquery.  move the javascript_include_tag call to the head tag and it should work.

Comment: that doesn't help. can you include a gist of your template and layout? and any errors.

Comment: Ok. I added more of what the files contain. That's the only error my app has right now.